# Why aren't ASP.NET MVC tag helpers creating the correct link?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an asp.net core MVC project with scaffolded Identity, and the tag helpers in the _LoginPartial view are acting wonky. In the Razor view, the link looks like this and don't navigate to any page or view.

```
  <a class="nav-link" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index">Manage Account</a>
```

but for some reason it's being rendered like this (taken from the dev console in chrome):

```
href="/?area=Identity&page=%2FAccount%2FManage%2FIndex"
```

I don't know why this is happening and I can't figure out how to get it to render properly and allow navigation to the correct page.

Comment: You should be using `asp-controller=".."` and `asp-action="..."`

Comment: asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" write like this=> asp-page="~/Account/Manage/Index"

Comment: @TazbirBhuiyan that throws an InvalidOperationException

Comment: default routing controller template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id}/{closeOnSubmit?}" How is your controller routing template?

Comment: app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

Comment: This all works fine for me with a freshly generated project (`dotnet new mvc -au Individual`). Try a fresh project yourself and if that works, look at any changes you've made to your own project. Changing over to use `asp-controller` and `asp-action` is not the solution here.

Comment: I didn't think so, since running a CLI command to generate a new project from scratch has identity working without adding any of my own controller or actions. I am trying to nail down what causes the changes to happen, since I clone a stable version of what I'm working on into a new directory, then scaffold in identity, and everything is fine for a a bit but then it starts generating the odd `href=` . I'll keep plugging away at this.

Comment: I had to delete my answer. This is a mess, including the docs and scouring the github issues. I found this hiding, it may be of some help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @AdamVincent I actually found out the issue. In the IdentityHostingStartup class in the `Configure` method, I had changed `services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>` to `services.AddIdentity(IdentityUser, IdentityRole>`  
It doesn't make sense to me why that changes how the URLs are generated, but as soon as I changed it back to `services.AddDefaultIdentity>` things returned to normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found out the issue. In the IdentityHostingStartup class in the Configure method of the `Identity` area, I had changed `services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>` to `services.AddIdentity(IdentityUser, IdentityRole>` It doesn't make sense to me why that changes how the URLs are generated, but as soon as I changed it back to `services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>` things returned to normal.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following

```
<a asp-area="Account"
  asp-controller="Manage"
  asp-action="Index">About Blog</a>
```

It will create following html

```
<a href="/Account/Manage/Index">About Blog</a>
```

If you have custom Route mapping like below

```
[Route("/Speaker/Evaluations", Name = "speakerevals")]
public IActionResult Evaluations() => View();
```

Then try

```
<a asp-route="speakerevals">Speaker Evaluations</a>
```

It will create html like below

```
<a href="/Speaker/Evaluations">Speaker Evaluations</a>
```

For more information click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: You absolutely can mix `<asp-area="..">` and `<asp-page="..">`, especially since that's how it's wired up in the template generated from the `dotnet new mvc --auth Individual` command